# laravel: Login form on non Laravel page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, authentication

I'm building a web application which is accompanied by a small website that uses Jekyll. Reason for this being that the website will almost never change and this way it is able to run fast (pure HTML+CSS and some JavaScript) and semi-independent of the application.

The Jekyll site is placed inside the Laravel public folder and runs fine. As it stands a user that wants to use our application needs to visit the default Laravel auth route to login (/login).

I would like to add a login form on one of my site pages that enables the user to login without visiting the application first.

Of course I tried adding a simple form and posting it to /login (the default Laravel route) but this won't work because Laravel expects a csrf token to be set.
I know Laravel sets a cookie containing the encrypted token but I'm not sure if (and how) I'm able to use this.

Is there any (simple) way of adding a login form to a NON-Laravel page? And is it possible to do so using only HTML & JavaScript (maybe using Ajax)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1- Cheapest option: disable csrf_token on the login route only. Some will recommend this, others will say you shouldn't. You can research online if you want to go this way or not.

2- Make an ajax GET request to a route that will return you the csrf_token so you can use it in your form. In your Laravel controller you simply return the session token

```
public function getToken() {
    return session()->token();
}
```

3 - Go the passport road for API requests the same as SPAs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: Thanks! Our application is already using passport but somehow I never figured I should use it to solve this problem.